# How to render enable/disable check box conditionally with database value in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I am new two JSF and Prime-faces. I suppose to finish the task and i almost completed but have to fix final requirement.

Here is the requirement:
The main objective of the task is to display the enable/disable check boxes associated with database values.
I have to do sorting and filtering values too.

Here is the picture what i have tried.
I can able to display the Boolean value or just empty check box or enable check-box.

[![In screenshot you can see that cmistes column displays all check-boxes in disabled mode and other two columns displays enabled but disabled as i wrote different code to check.][1]][1]

Here is the code to display:
The below code display only disabled checkboxes..

```
<p:column sortBy="#{dossier.cmistes}" width="85" filterBy="#{dossier.cmistes}" filterStyle="width:50px; font-size:10px;">
                        <f:facet name="header">Cmistes</f:facet>
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="cmistes"  disabled="#{dossierBean.dossier.cmistes}" styleClass="benefSelection" />
</p:column>
```

And this code displays enabled check-box but not disabled..

```
<p:column sortBy="#{dossier.vbtaz}" width="85" filterBy="#{dossier.vbtaz}" filterStyle="width:50px; font-size:10px;">
                            <f:facet name="header">vbtaz</f:facet>
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="vbtaz"  checked = "true"  rendered="#{dossier.vbtaz}" styleClass="benefSelection" />
</p:column>
```

Generated getters and setters are:

```
private Boolean cmistes; //IND_CMISTES NUMBER(1,0)
public Boolean getCmistes() {
        return cmistes;
    }

    public void setCmistes(Boolean cmistes) {
        this.cmistes = cmistes;
    }
```

Any suggestion ?
Thanks.

Comment: Juste remove the `== '1'`

Comment: In primefaces, Datatable has an attribute call "selection" http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie.. I have removed =='1' . the output is showing only disabled checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to show ALL checkboxes, but you want them to be enabled or disabled depending on your database data.

First, you are currently using the `rendered` attribute which tells the server to generate or not the HTML code. You want to use the `disabled` attribute like this :

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="cmistes" disabled="#{dossierBean.dossier.cmistes}" styleClass="benefSelection" />
```

Also note the `== '1'` is removed, because your method is already returning a Boolean, and don't expect the right result by comparing a Boolean with a String.

**More info :**

- [h:selectBooleanCheckbox](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/selectBooleanCheckbox.html)

Comment: @AIexandre ... tried with the code what you mentioned ..after adding that code ... i can see only all check-boxes are on disabled mode..but i should display enabled/disabled both values associated with data values..

Comment: @Alexandre.. At finally i got an output using disabled attribute...I know the mistake what i did before . I used disabled ="#{dossierBean.dossier.cmistes}"  instead of  disabled="#{dossier.cmistes}".Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,here is the solution for the above question which i only asked.

I used disabled attribute to display rendered /disabled check-boxes.

```
    <p:column sortBy="#{dossier.cmistes}" width="85" filterBy="#{dossier.cmistes}" filterStyle="width:50px; font-size:10px;">
            <f:facet name="header">Cmistes</f:facet>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="cmistes" disabled="true" value="#{dossier.cmistes}" styleClass="benefSelection" />
    </p:column>
  <p:column sortBy="#{dossier.vbtaz}" width="85" filterBy="#{dossier.vbtaz}" filterStyle="width:50px; font-size:10px;">
            <f:facet name="header">vbtaz</f:facet>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="vbtaz"  disabled="true" value="#{dossier.vbtaz}" styleClass="benefSelection" />
  </p:column>
```

But, If i want to display check-boxes  with tick symbol instead of gray color..
Any sugestion?

Comment: And please learn some basic html/css and jsf you made several basic mistakes  (`checked` is not a good attribute for jsf, and the 'grey'  is because it is disabled, being checked is a different thing etc..)

Comment: By default all is rendered, `rendered="true"` is useless.